# simple login form using java and db2 . everything ok but still resultset empty

Tags: java

I am trying to make a simple login form. Every thing is working fine, connection is established, query is executed but `ResultSet` is still empty so always getting redirected to fail.jsp. No error no warning at all.

**Servlet code:**

```
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
    String name = request.getParameter("name");
    String password = request.getParameter("password");
    modelclass md = new modelclass();
    daoclass dao = new daoclass();
    md.setName(name);
    md.setPassword(password);
    System.out.println("this just before the sql query on the main servlet page");
    String sql = "Select * from USERADD where name = ? and password= ?";
    String result = dao.guser(md, sql);
    if (result.equals("success")) {
        response.sendRedirect("welcome.jsp");
    } else {
        response.sendRedirect("fail.jsp");
    }

}
```

This is the DAO class which makes connection.

**Data Access code(dao.java):**

```
public class daoclass {

    public static String username = "NickNeo";
    public static String password = "123123";
    public static String driver = "com.ibm.db2.jcc.DB2Driver";
    public static String url = "jdbc:db2://localhost:50000/CITYLIFE";
    public static Connection con = null;
    public static PreparedStatement ps = null;

    static {

        try {
            Class.forName(driver);
            System.out.println("before connection");
            con = DriverManager.getConnection(url, username, password);
            System.out.println("Connection Successfullll......!!!!!!");
        } catch(Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    public String guser(modelclass obj, String sql) {

        try {
            System.out.println("entry into try block");
            ps=con.prepareStatement(sql);
            ps.setString(1, obj.getName());
            ps.setString(2, obj.getPassword());
            System.out.println("before query");
            ResultSet rs = ps.executeQuery();
            System.out.println("query executed");
            int i = 0;
            while(rs.next()) {
                System.out.println("entered into while loop");
                ++i;
            }
            if (i >= 1) {
                return "success";
            } else {
                System.out.println("this is inside else of while block");
                return "fail";
            }

        } catch(Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        System.out.println("this is the most outer fail statement");
        return "fail";
    }
}
```

the `rs` is always empty. tried many things but still getting `rs` as empty. please help

Comment: Try to print the username and password when you receive the request to validate you are sending the correct values in the SQL query.

Comment: i just deleted it and write from starting. i still don't know the mistake in this code. wrote exactly the same code again and that worked. thanks